# download mysql database by compressing data using gzip in php

Tags: php, mysql

guys I have a problem in downloading database from mysql compressed. It has a large size that why I want it compressed. Here is my code to download database from mysql using php in gzip. But it downloads a corrupt file.

```
$filename = "backup" . date("YmdHis") . ".sql.gz";
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_database = "movies";
$dir = "path/to/file/";
$cmd = "mysqldump -h {$db_host} -u {$db_username} --password={$db_password} {$db_database} | gzip > {$dir}{$filename}";
exec($cmd);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
passthru("cat {$dir}{$filename}");
```

Comment: Is the ZIP file created successfully? Try running the same command in the terminal first to see if it works.

Comment: Yes it is, but its size is much lower than expected, 2Bytes but database has large size

Comment: Try the mysqldump command only and make sure that works first.